# How am I able to replace multiple substrings in one string?

Tags: java

Is it possible to `replace()` multiple strings at once?

---

For example:

```
String X = new String("I will find cookies");
String newX = X.replace(("will", "won't") + ("I", "You"));
System.out.print(newX);
```

OUTPUT

> You won't find cookies

I know what I did was wrong and will create an error but at least you get my idea of "replacing  multiples". If it's possible, what would be the better solution to this?

Comment: How about calling `replace` multiple times?

Comment: My output string would change, wouldn't it? I have tried it, and the replaced strings would just `append` to my output or maybe I'm just doing it wrong. Can you call `replace` multiple times w/o changing the output?

Comment: Your string won't change because it's immutable, but the result of that will have the replacements you're looking for. For example, you can do this: `newX = X.replace("will", "won't").replace("I", "You");`

Comment: What does "*at once*" mean in your case?

Comment: Ohhh im newbie at java. Still on my freshman year tho. Anyway, if that's right and would fit my question, you should put your comment as an answer so people would see it! :)

Comment: I think @LuiggiMendoza explained it very well already. Problem solved. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest answer (I can think of) here is:

```
String newX = X.replace("will", "won't").replace("I", "You");
```

This will be find for a simple example like this, but if you're trying to do anything bigger (i.e. many more replacements), you'd be wise to look into regular expressions instead.

Comment: Also, you haven't mentioned this in your question, but if you're hoping to replace multiple instances in the same string, for example, if your input were `I will find cookies, will you?`, and you wanted to replace both instances of `will`, you could use `X.replaceAll()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a chained call of `replace()` like below:

```
String X = new String("I will find cookies");
String newX = X.replace("will", "won't").replace("I", "You");
System.out.print(newX);
```